# How to explode array[string] field and group data for one pass

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new in scala and spark and don't know how to explode "path" field and found max and min "event_dttm" field for one pass.
I have a data:

```
val weblog=sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("39f0412b4c91","staticnavi.com", Seq( "panel", "cm.html" ), 1424954530, "SO.01"),
  ("39f0412b4c91","staticnavi.com", Seq( "panel", "cm.html" ), 1424964830, "SO.01"),
  ("39f0412b4c91","staticnavi.com", Seq( "panel", "cm.html" ), 1424978445, "SO.01"),
   )).toDF("id","domain","path","event_dttm","load_src")
```

I must to get next result:

```
"id"        |   "domain"   |"newPath" | "max_time" | min_time   | "load_src"
39f0412b4c91|staticnavi.com|  panel   | 1424978445 | 1424954530 | SO.01
39f0412b4c91|staticnavi.com|  cm.html | 1424978445 | 1424954530 | SO.01
```

I think it's possible realize via row function, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `explode()`, followed by a `groupBy` aggregation:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode, min, max}

var result = weblog.withColumn("path", explode($"path"))
  .groupBy("id","domain","path","load_src")
  .agg(min($"event_dttm").as("min_time"),
       max($"event_dttm").as("max_time"))

result.show()
+------------+--------------+-------+--------+----------+----------+
|          id|        domain|   path|load_src|  min_time|  max_time|
+------------+--------------+-------+--------+----------+----------+
|39f0412b4c91|staticnavi.com|  panel|   SO.01|1424954530|1424978445|
|39f0412b4c91|staticnavi.com|cm.html|   SO.01|1424954530|1424978445|
+------------+--------------+-------+--------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine. 
Is there another way w/o using explode?

Comment: using the `rdd` api, but that's going to be more elaborate and potentially slower.

Comment: I've found solution with flatMap: val result = weblog.flatMap { 
   case Row(id: String, domain: String, path: String, event_dttm: Long, load_src: String, ymd: String) => {
                            path.split("/").map(x => (id, domain.concat("#").concat(x), BigInt(event_dttm), load_src, ymd))
}}